# "Early Access" - What does this mean?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

What does this tag mean? I purchased a shotgun at level 6 because it said when you purchase with Zen you get "Early Access", but I can't use it. Have I read this wrong or have I just been conned out of my money and now have to get to level 20 when everyone else can use the same thing and it won't be fun?

Comment: Did you just buy it for 1 day and wanted to use it later so it expired? Or did you actually buy it permanently?

Comment: No worries, I was being retarded and thought it was a primary. I'm now the proud owner of the shotgun with fire rounds and orange tiger camo. xD Perm too.

Comment: Congratulations hope you like it, and if you do they are making releasing the Sar-k soon, Full auto Shotgun ;D

Comment: You should consider answering and accepting your own answer to mark this as having a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

"Early Access" means that you can use Zen to bypass the level restriction on certain gear. For example, this means that even if you're level 10, you can spend Zen to use equipment like a Shotgun receiver, which requires level 20.  Time restrictions still apply, so not all Zen purchases are permanent.