# How does Early Access work?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Early Access” - What does this mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78743/early-access-what-does-this-mean)

I'm thinking of using the Early Access for the Anti-Materiel Rifle, but I'm not sure if it unlocks permanently, and I can later purchase it with GP, or it is just usable for a day and then it locks again.

How does Early Access work?